# What is the relation between ADF faces and Trinidad?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, trinidad

I was looking into the documentation of [ADF Faces TreeMap component](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16162_01/apirefs.1112/e17490/tagdoc/dvt_treemap.html) and got a little bit surprised by the namespace of the event called `AttributeChangeEvent` that this partcular component supports  ie  `org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.event.AttributeChangeEvent` . What exactly is the relation between ADF Faces and Trinidad ? Is one the super set of another ? What exactly is the history behind these namespaces ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Trinidad used to be ADF 10g.  Oracle gave ADF to the Apache foundation (minus some stuff) and started work on ADF 11g.  As such, Oracle 11g depends on a lot of the core libraries that are now maintained by the Apache foundation.

In fact, the `afh:` namespace is often used as `trh:` since it's now properly in the Trindad libraries.